# How to open an activity instantly and then loading its layout

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android, inflate

Here's the deal: I have a heavy layout that cannot be improved any further, as it contains LinearLayouts with weights (so I cannot use RelativeLayouts).
In Activity A, I click on a list item that fires off Activity B. **Activity A freezes until Activity B is fully loaded**, then Activity B gets shown. So this is the complete queue of events:

1. Activity A: open B
2. Activity A: freezes
3. Activity B: finishes inflation/setContentView
4. Activity A: goes back into the application stack
5. Activity B: gets shown

How can I **immediately show Activity B** so that Activity A won't freeze?
I thought about inflating a temporary layout in B, but I need a callback method that tells me that B is fully visible and I can then replace the temporary layout with the *real* one.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Off topic: layout inflation in Android is a real pain, it shouldn't block the whole UI, but it does. Same thing for setting list adapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do your time taking task of Activity B in thread and if you need to update the UI after your task completes then do it using handler.

Comment: Problem is I actually do nothing but setContentView. Is it possible to know when an Activity is visible? That's the moment when I want to load the layout and replace the temporary one.

Comment: it simply is: `setContentView(R.layout.m_layout);`

Comment: I have not worked with fragments but without fragments your activity is loading in no time. So please check fragments.

Comment: I know, the slow loading is caused by fragment_2, but I cannot optimize it any further. I simply would like to know if there is a method that Android automatically calls as soon as the layout is loaded and the Activity is shown. Because that's when I want to inflate a second (the one above) layout.

Answer (score -1):

You can do your time consuming loading using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) .You can use

```
 doInBackgroundMethod to load the data
 onProgressUpdate you can bind your layout to data.
```

If you works this way your Activity will not be frozen

Comment: This is not possible: the UI can be updated from the UI thread only. Which means: no AsyncTask.

Comment: onPreExecute,onProgressUpdate,onPostExecute run in the same UI thread.So we use this class

Comment: And that's the problem, it would still block the UI thread. The time consuming load is setContentView, not any other operation.

Comment: ok,You are not understanding what I said.You can do this.AsyncTask class is designed for this

Comment: I tried and used an AsyncTask with the following:
`@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
         setContentView(R.layout.m_layout);
        }`

Nothing changed.